# addMessageMarkers from util::ResourceMarkers is very slow

Tags: rascal

The method *addMessageMarkers* from *util::ResourceMarkers* is very slow; adding one message may take several seconds.

Take the Java project HelloWorld with one Java file:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int i = 42;
     System.out.println("Hello World! with value: "+i);
   }
}
```

First do

```
import util::ResourceMarkers;
```

Then running

```
addMessageMarkers({error("numLiteral, value:42",|project://HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java|(83,2,<4,10>,<4,12>))});
```

takes 7 - 8 seconds.

Note that when we change the location into a non-existing one, like

```
addMessageMarkers({error("numLiteral, value:42",|file://dummy.java|(83,2,<4,10>,<4,12>))});
```

then it runs much faster, without any warning.

So, I have two questions:

- 1. Why does *addMessageMarkers()* run so slow, can I change something to make it run faster?

  2. Is it possible for *addMessageMarkers()* to return the messages it was not able to add.

BTW, yesterday I posted a question *How to construct a consistent location?*, the motivation was that I wanted to test *addMessageMarker* with a larger set of (proper) messages. When more messages are passed, then the run-time increases as well, I do not have precise figures yet.

Comment: Before the release of november 2014 (0.7.0) this used to be slow due to a lock contention bug but now it is expected to be fast. Are you on that version?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, I will upgrade asap, and check the version before any future post. Thanks.

Comment: it was a good question still.